# How to set a timeout for the html in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a rss reader and use JEditorpane to display the discription, which is html content. However, if a url is dead, the whole program would be stuck. And my question is, if there is a way to add a timeout to it? Or there might be some better solutions?

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [mre] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `setPage` method, create a URLConnection yourself, so you can set its timeout attributes directly, then pass the connection’s InputStream to JEditorPane’s [read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");

// Five seconds
long timeout = 5000;

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);

editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {
    editorPane.read(stream, editorPane.getDocument());
}
```

Except…

If a JEditorPane loads HTML from an InputStream only to discover a header or meta element declares a different charset, the JEditorPane needs to start over.  It signals this need by throwing [ChangedCharSetException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/ChangedCharSetException.html).

At that point, it is necessary to create an HTMLDocument, set its `"IgnoreCharsetDirective"` property, and use the newly discovered charset to create a Reader and load the URL directly into the document from that Reader.

So, the amended version looks like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");

// Five seconds
int timeout = 5000;

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);

editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {
    editorPane.read(stream, editorPane.getDocument());
} catch (ChangedCharSetException e) {
    String newContentType = e.getCharSetSpec();
    editorPane.setContentType(newContentType);

    EditorKit editorKit = editorPane.getEditorKit();
    Document doc = editorKit.createDefaultDocument();
    doc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", true);
    editorPane.setDocument(doc);

    String charset;
    try {
        charset = new DataFlavor(newContentType).getParameter("charset");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        throw new IOException(ce);
    }

    connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);

    try (Reader reader =
        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), charset)) {

        editorKit.read(reader, doc, 0);
    } catch (BadLocationException le) {
        throw new IOException(le);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply! However, the most confusing thing to me is to set a timeout for the links inside the xml content. For example, the xml content is <img  src="https://a-dead.com/link.jpg" />, and if it's put into the JEditorpane by `read()`, it would be stuck and seems no timeout existed.

Comment: That’s probably going to be a lot harder.  All I can think of is [setting the global URLStreamHandlerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29), which turns out to be a fairly big endeavor.